# Tab bar controller not appearing correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to connect Tab Bar Controller to existing part of my app, but when I do that it's "malfunctioning".

However when I run Tab Bar Controller part standalone as initial view controller it works properly like in the image below :

[image]

This is how app looks when it is run(correct behavior) :

[image]

However when I go to this tab bar controller from my main app this is how it looks like this:

[image]

My main app looks like this :

Scroll View contains

- UIView 1
- UIView 2
- UIView 3
- UIView x

Each view does something not related to this tab bar controller. Only one view view x tries to "visit" tab bar controller and display some data there, but it's not. Any ideas?

I have this tab bar controller identifier set to test, and I here is how I do that from my view x :

```
UITabBarController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test"];
        [self.view addSubview:newViewController.view];
```

**EDIT :**

Entire app :

[image]

I'm creating views programatically. That's why I don't have any relationships/segues to the tab bar controller.

**SOLUTION :**

Change :

```
UITabBarController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test"];
            [self.view addSubview:newViewController.view];
```

To :

```
UITabBarController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test"];
        [self addChildViewController:newViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:newViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a root viewController to the navigation Controller

Comment: I want just one of my many views to point to Navigation Controler, I still want to start with my app(root view Controller from where it is starting currently). Maybe I'm miss interpreting your answer, could give a more elaborate answer?thanks

Comment: try to change the function "Addsubview" to "Addchildviewcontroller" in the tabbarviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Just **don't** do this. From the Apple [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) referenece

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

As I understand it means you must use UITabBarController only as a root view controller of the window. But you can alway use a general UIViewController and add UITabBar there.

(The view offset problem you've met is possible to be fixed, it will not follow the Apple guidelines however and not advised).

Comment: that is a valid point, how would you recommend I go about this. I want this tab bar controller to be used for options in my app, and I need to arrange them in some kind of tabs so user wouldn't be overflown with information. How would you implement this, +1 for the answer

Comment: I would recommend to use UISegmentedControl for a settings view, it should be good with the Apple guidelines and should perfectly match user experience (as an example see the Wi-Fi network details view in the Settings app). If you really want to use a TabBar in the middle of navigation hierarchy, and it must be associated with the TabBar and nothing else, be ready for the app being rejected (I'm not saying it will, but it could be). If you need any tutorial of UISegmentedControl or UITabBar instead of UITabBarController, you could try to Google for details, there're many of them ready for you.